# Lamba depending on template depending value as default value of constructor of that template fails on MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, clang++

I just upgraded my msvc and got into a trouble.

Here is Minimal Complete Verifiable Example which reproduce issue in my old code:

```cpp
#include <functional>

#define VERSION 1

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    static constexpr int bar = 512;

#if VERSION == 1
    Foo(std::function<int()> f = []() { return Foo<T>::bar;})
#elif VERSION == 2
    Foo(std::function<int()> f = []() { return Foo::bar;})
#elif VERSION == 3
    Foo(std::function<int()> f = []() { return bar;})
#elif VERSION == 4
    Foo(std::function<int()> f = [bar = Foo<T>::bar]() { return bar;})
#endif
        : m_f{std::move(f)}
    {}

public:
    std::function<int()> m_f;
};


void use()
{
    Foo<int> foo;
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GEjz86)

When `VERSION` is defined as `1` this is similar to my original code.
I have to support also clang and gcc. Curretly my project is using C++17 standard (C++20 my project may use in next year or two).

I'm looking for some nice workaround which will not require nasty `#if` and cover all compilers (old new `msvc` `gcc` `clang`).

Other values of `VERSION` demonstrate what I have tried so far (always some compiler is failing).

| VERSION | which compilers fails |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | msvc 19.28 |
| 2 | msvc 19.28, msvc 19.27, msvc 19.25 |
| 3 | msvc all versions |
| 4 | clang 11.0 |

If someone knows respective bug report for MSVC link would be nice too.

Easiest fix is move constant to global scope, but I prefer to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

static function does the job:

```
static std::function<int()> defaultF() {return []() { return bar;};}

Foo(std::function<int()> f = defaultF())
    : m_f{std::move(f)}
{}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qh1so4)